# Prevalence of combination of factors (in R)

Tags: r, combinations

I'm investigating the role of a combination of tumor pattern in predicting its malignancy. 
I have this table of thyroid nodules characteristics described by 6 categorical variables (YES/NO).

```
ID color shape halo calcium margins solid
1    1     1    1      1       0      0
2    1     1    0      0       1      0
3    0     0    1      1       1      1
4    0     0    1      0       0      0
5    1     1    1      1       0      1
```

I would like to know the prevalence of the combination of the presence of the three of them.
In this example would be:

```
          combination freq
color, shape, calcium   2
shape, halo,  calcium   2
color, shape, margins   1
....
```

I ended-up with the prevalence of each of them

```
as.data.frame(table(tiradsLong$caratteristica, tiradsLong$valore))
```

which is not my aim.

Thanks in advance,
Angelo

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution I could come up with, which I am sure can be improved in elegance:

```
x <- combn(2:ncol(df), 3)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
              apply(x, 2, function(y)
                    list(cols = names(df)[y],
                    value = sum(rowSums(df[, y]) == 3)))))
```

Output is:

```
                   cols value
1    color, shape, halo     2
2 color, shape, calcium     2
3 color, shape, margins     1
4   color, shape, solid     1
5  color, halo, calcium     2
...
...
```

In general, you may want to look at frequent itemsets and apriori (arules package) for such things.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for even though it doesn't work so far...
 
    
      Error in rowSums(tiradsWide[, y]) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Please check the class of your columns. Also, you can check the class of let us say tiradsWide[, c(2, 3, 4] as an example. It works fine on my side.

Comment: Yes, the columns are of list type. Apply returns a matrix (list type). Some massaging can get into a proper data frame of desired type. But, the logic and output are correct.

Comment: ok, i follow your suggestion (converting columns in numeric) and it works very well, as expected. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The following solution depends on how your data is formatted. It would be very helpful if you provide some sample data via `dput` or similar.

Anyhow, the following is one of the many possible solutions.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:50,
                 color = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
                 shape = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
                 halo = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
                 calcium = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
                 margins = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
                 solid = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob = 0.5))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather("feature", "value", - ID) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(fdata = paste(sort(feature), collapse = "_")) %>%
  group_by(fdata) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Using `dplyr`, first you need to transform your data into a *long* format. Then you can filter for your signals, i.e., `1`. With grouping by ids you can encode sets of features and combine them into one string. The `sort` is nescessary, since we need to add some structure to the encoded strings. Afterwads we group by the encoded strings and count the number of ID in the group.

**Edit:**
With the hint of @Gopala that you want only three groups you could add these lines to the above snippet:

```
... %>%
    mutate(threeCombos = purrr::map(fdata, function(.x) {
      splittedStrings = unlist(strsplit(.x, "_"))
      if (length(splittedStrings) > 2) {
        res <- data.frame(t(combn(splittedStrings, m = 3)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
          unite("threecombs", starts_with("X"), sep = ",")
      } else {
        res <- data.frame()
      }
      return(res)
    })) %>% 
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(threecombs) %>%
    summarise(freq = sum(count))
```

This *may* compute faster than going throgh choose(n,m) combinations. But again, it depends on the further statisitical analysis what you want to do with the triplets.

Comment: Why do you think this gives the correct (desired) result articulated above?

Comment: You think it is wrong because column names (combination, freq) and separator "_" are wrong?

Comment: On the original data, this gives 5 rows of output whereas there are 20 possible combinations of 3 columns. Additionally, this one generates more than 3 column combinations.

Comment: Indeed. I wonder why this limit of 3 exist? What kind of statistical analysis does OP want to do?